# lastb output empty even after 3 failed login (su) attempts

Tags: security, su

On one terminal

```
root@Andromeda:~# lastb

btmp begins Sat Mar  2 10:03:44 2019
```

On another one:

```
$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for pkaramol: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pkaramol: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pkaramol: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Back to the first terminal again

```
root@Andromeda:~# lastb

btmp begins Sat Mar  2 10:03:44 2019
```

Why `lastb` isn't logging the failed `su` attempts?

Using `Ubuntu 18.04.02`

Comment: Try to login in normally. sudo login attempts are usually in /var/log/secure, at least in RH based systems.